A question on modules
I'm recently studying modules. One example I saw for a module was the module $V$ over the ring of polynomials $F[x]$, where $V$ is a vector space over the field $F$, wich defined as follow:
Given a linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow V$, any vector $v\in V$, and any polynomial $p(x)\in F[x]$, $pv=p(T)(v)$.
My question is why is this a module?
[ Three of the demands I understood why the met:
If $p,q\in F[x]$, and $v,s\in F$, then
$p(v+s)=pv+ps$ as $p(T)$ is linear,
$(p+q)v=pv+qv$ and $\operatorname{Id}(v)=v$ by definition.
But I haven't understood why $p(qv)=(pq)v$ :
$p(qv)$ is polynomial composition, while $(pq)v$ is polynomial miltiplication.]

No, $p(qv)$ is not polynomial composition.

You write that the definition is $p(X)v = p(T)(v)$. So, you need to prove that $p(X)(q(X)v) = (p(X)q(X))v$.

Let $p=\sum a_iX^i$, $q=\sum b_jX^j$, then $$(pq)v=(\sum_\limits{i,j}a_ib_jX^{i+j})v=\sum_\limits{i,j}a_ib_jT^{i+j}(v),$$
and
$$p(qv)=p(\sum b_jT^j(v))=\sum a_iT^i(\sum b_jT^j(v))=\sum_\limits{i,j}a_ib_jT^i(T^j(v))=\sum_\limits{i,j}a_ib_jT^{i+j}(v).$$

Thanks on the clear proof. Could you give some specific example so I could fully understad?

@user1360376 Let $T$ be some diagonal matrix?
